# getting difference between dates and create a rank in python

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am building a user system, where each users has a profile page. I run a cron job every week to give points to users based on which ones updated their profile most recently. For this I have between 1-100 points to give.

The idea is for ex: if user `A` updated their profile today, user `A` would get `100 points`, if the profile was updated yesterday it would be `99 points` and the day before that would be `98 points` and so on

If any user updated their profile last 100 days ago or more, then the score would be `0`.

Now, the problem I have is changing the date of `updated_on` to number.

I have this code, which I am fetching from database, but I am stuck.

```
updated_on = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(updated_on_date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()

if updated_on   .... ?:
    rank  = 100
elif
   ...
```

Comment: what is the "database"? If you are using a db it sounds like you want to update based on a select

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am using database (mariadb), I will submit the value of `rank` to a users table with the user id.

Comment: What kind of object is `updated_on_date`? Also, is it in UTC?

Comment: It is a date from the database, in this format `2014-02-14 12:30:56` @PM2Ring

Comment: Can you not add this logic into the db itself?  Update using the timestamp?

Comment: Thanks. But you _still_ didn't say whether the database dates are in UTC or local time. In my answer I assume that these dates _are_ in UTC, since using local times leads to chaos and madness. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do `str(updated_on_date)` since `updated_on_date` is already a string. I'll assume that these dates are in UTC, since using local times leads to madness. :)

You can get the current datetime in UTC using `current_date = datetime.utcnow()`. In the code below, I'll just hard-code today's date so that future readers will get the same output that I do.

The `datetime` module supplies a `datetime.timedelta` object, which allows you to perform arithmetic with `datetime.datetime` objects. You can add a `timedelta` to a `datetime` to get a new `datetime`, and if you subtract one `datetime` from another the result is a `timedelta`. So it's very easy to get the number of days between two dates.

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = (
    '2016-03-08 00:00:00',
    '2016-03-07 00:00:00',
    '2016-03-01 00:00:00',
    '2015-11-30 00:00:00',
    '2015-11-29 00:00:00',
    '2015-11-20 00:00:00',
)

#current_date = datetime.utcnow()
current_date = datetime(2016, 3, 8)
print('current', current_date)

for datestr in dates:
    updated_on = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    delta = (current_date - updated_on).days
    rank = max(0, 100 - delta)
    print('updated', updated_on, 'delta', delta, 'rank', rank)
```

**output**

```
current 2016-03-08 00:00:00
updated 2016-03-08 00:00:00 delta 0 rank 100
updated 2016-03-07 00:00:00 delta 1 rank 99
updated 2016-03-01 00:00:00 delta 7 rank 93
updated 2015-11-30 00:00:00 delta 99 rank 1
updated 2015-11-29 00:00:00 delta 100 rank 0
updated 2015-11-20 00:00:00 delta 109 rank 0
```

Comment: Thanks but, why do you have an array of `dates`? I have no such thing. I only wanted to give users ranks starting from today.

Comment: Oops, never mind. Forget the above. just one quick question, if I wanted to measure by weeks/months, it would suffice to change `.days` to `.months` or `.weeks` right?

Comment: No and yes. :) Take a look at the [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) docs. It does have a `.weeks` attribute, but it doesn't have a months attribute because that would be impossible, due to month lengths not being constant. A `timedelta` is a datetime _difference_ and a `timedelta` spanning several months has no idea of the actual lengths of the months it spans. You _can_ get an approximation though, by dividing the days by 30.6.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today = date.today()
>>> sample = [date(2015,5,27), date(2016,3,4), date(2015,12,31), today]
>>> for updated_on in sample:
...     delta = today - updated_on
...     rank = max(0, 100 - delta.days)
...     print("updated on: {} -> rank: {}".format(updated_on, rank))
...
updated on: 2015-05-27 -> rank: 0
updated on: 2016-03-04 -> rank: 96
updated on: 2015-12-31 -> rank: 32
updated on: 2016-03-08 -> rank: 100
```

Comment: this still does not answer the question. I don't have a range of dates, I only have one date in mind, and that is today. How can I use your `for` loop with just one day?

Answer (score 0):

Using this example you can calculate number of days between two dates:

```
date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str('2016-01-01 23:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str('2016-03-08 23:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
number_of_days = date2 -date1
print(number_of_days.days)
```

will print the total number of days between `date1` and `date2`.